# No source for msvcr100d.dll!__CrtDumpMemoryLeaks()

Tags: c++, visual-studio, debugging, visual-c++, msvcrt

When debugging a C++ Project using Visual Studio 2010, it cannot find the source for crt. When I am trying to go inside one such module, it displays "No Source Available". It also does not provide an option to `Browse` so that I can help it locate the source location.

Under the Option Solution->Common Properties->Debug Source Files, the proper location to the crt source is updated.

In lack of source level debugging of crt I have to read through the disassemble which is getting difficult.

Can anyone help me figure out what might be going wrong?

Please Note ** I am using an external build system via Visual Studio to build my C++ Project.

**With the guidance of Hans here how I narrowed down to the problem.**

While the breakpoint was still active, I listed all the Symbol Load information. I realized that `msvcr100d.i386.pdb` did not match the dll. It actually went all the way down to fetch from the microsoft public symbol store which off course had the symbols stripped off. So that was the root cause of my problem.

And here is a similar problem in [social.msdn](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vsdebug/thread/99383962-0969-4ed0-b42c-34611df307ac/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see the cause of the problem by using Debug + Windows + Modules while you have a break active.  Right-click msvcr100d.dll and select "Symbol Load Information" to get info about the .pdb that the debugger uses.

For some reason the Microsoft Symbol Server supplies one that has the source info stripped.  It is probably intentional, something to do with service and security patches of the DLL getting out of sync with the source code in vc/crt/scr.  You can get a real answer instead of a guess by posting to connect.microsoft.com

A workaround of sorts is to compile your code with /MTd instead of /MDd, if that's possible at all.  Project + Properties, C/C++, Code Generation, Runtime Library setting.  The debugger will then use the .pdb file in vc/lib.  Do keep your eyes on the ball, debug your code instead of the CRT's.

Comment: Thank you for your response. It would be a bit difficult to change the compiler switch partly because it might change the behavior and wholly because I am using an external build system. But saying that, what you are saying is making sense to me. Time-stamp mismatch could be possible. I think connect.microsoft.com would be ideal for this query. Thank you again.

Comment: It is not a time-stamp mismatch.  The .pdb had all source file and line info stripped.  This is otherwise pretty typical for DLLs built in release mode, all the .pdbs for the Windows DLLs are shipped that way for example.  Not in the least because you don't have any source code.  It is however not a release mode DLL and you do have source :)  Could be a silly mistake, connect can tell you.

Comment: Bingo :-) You are correct. I was thinking mismatch timestamp between pdb and dll but could not believe they actually stripped off the symbols. Here is how I verified it from the debug output `Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcr100d.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).`

Answer (score 0):

You can find the sources for the CRT in your installation folder, subfolder VC\CRT\SRC.

If they're not there, did you install them when installing VS2010? (not sure whether you can really choose this).

Comment: As I mentioned the source is present under VC\CRT\SRC but IDE cannot locate it. I would like to know how can I let IDE aware of the location of the CRT Source